# add or delete library in project in eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add and delete libraries in a project in eclipse plugin development. For example, there is the JRE System Library or an ivy library. I would like to delete one of these libraries and add another one. I am using IProject, IWorkbench, etc. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the Eclipse JDT APIs such as `IJavaProject`, see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) for examples of changing the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.right click on the project
2.go to java build path
3.Add library
4.select the appropriate options
5.click finish and you are good to go

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do that. I am asking from a coding perspective how to do it.